# Ionic, error when generating production build

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm stuck with an error that I cannot solve.

The error started when trying to create the build with *--prod*, I was fixing, updating dependencies and currently when executing `ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose` I get:

> typescript error
>   'ion-icon' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module. 2. If 'ion-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the
>   '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (">  [ERROR ->] 
>    ")
>
> 'ion-buttons' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-buttons' is an Angular component, then verify that it is
>   part of this module. 2. If 'ion-buttons' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the
>   '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("   [ERROR ->]  ")
>
> 'ion-col' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-col' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module. 2. If 'ion-col' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'
>   of this component to suppress this message. ("   [ERROR
>   ->]
>
> Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
>    Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
>       at C:\Users\ceman\Desktop\idem-app-updated-master\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
>       at step (C:\Users\ceman\Desktop\idem-app-updated-master\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
>       at Object.next (C:\Users\ceman\Desktop\idem-app-updated-master\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
>       at fulfilled (C:\Users\ceman\Desktop\idem-app-updated-master\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
>   [ERROR] Command not found: ionic-app-scripts
>       ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received +0ms
>       ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 queued functions +0ms
>       ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: exiting (exit code 127) +0ms

These are my files, tell me if you need to see another:

**app.module.ts:** https://pastebin.com/TXQ4tDFM

**package.json:** https://pastebin.com/kAK5eK5Z

This is my configuration according to `ionic info`:

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0-rc.9 (C:\Users\ceman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
```

Cordova:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v6.14.3 (P:\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.1.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment:

```
ANDROID_HOME : P:\Android\sdk
```

I add an extra data, I had updated to Node 8 to see if this corrected something and nothing, I returned to version 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `IonicModule` in your `module.ts` & then use it like this:

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(yourPage)
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed IonicModule into component.module.ts or some other module you used ion-icon, ion-buttons, ion-col