# How to fix build failed issue in Ionic 3 for android?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

When I try `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` command in Ionic 3, it shows an error

> [12:24:50] ionic-app-script task: “build”
>   [12:24:50] Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
>   Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
>   at /Users/angelamal/Documents/osome/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
>   at step (/Users/angelamal/Documents/osome/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
>   at Object.next (/Users/angelamal/Documents/osome/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
>   at fulfilled (/Users/angelamal/Documents/osome/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
>   ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited
>   with exit code 1.

While I try to build an android app in Ionic 3.

I used this command `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

But it is showing an error. How to solve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you share your ionic info output ?

Comment: Please add more info of your error so we can help you on that.

Comment: Don't forget to use the `--verbose` option when building. It will give you more details

Comment: If the message says...  Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above Error:.... Why haven't you included earlier messages. That would give you hint surely..

Comment: Perhaps this will give a clue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124742/ionic-error-when-generating-production-build "You need to import IonicModule in your module.ts"

Comment: Run `ngc` in your project root to highlight errors that would make it through JIT but not AOT compilation and fix those first. Warning: will produce lots of metadata.

Comment: @AlexSteinberg how can I run ngc on the project root?  ionic cli 6.13.1 ionic-angular 3.9.2 app-scripts 3.24, cordova cli 11.0.0, nodejs 10.16.0, npm 6.9.0  Thank you. I am getting (Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule) followed by (Error: The Angular AoT build failed) building PWA with (ionic cordova build browser --prod --release) it's happy if I drop --prod :( in the meantime I am running (npm run lint) over and over to cleanup stuff.

Comment: @AlexSteinberg you may have insights on similar where I am able to provide a bit more details.  Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245178/how-can-i-upgrade-node-js-to-v14-x-with-ionic-3