# How can I upgrade Node JS to v14.x with Ionic 3?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

According to errors I faced with this TS/Node project (for a simple TypeScript only REST API) the suggested fix (mentioned here (https://github.com/heineiuo/rippledb/issues/148)) is that I needed something like Node v14.x
I initially jumped all the way v18.x and that tutorial project built and worked.  https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/using-typescript-with-mongodb-tutorial

However, Node 18.x and even downgrading to Node v14.15.5 breaks the build apk and browser processes in one ionic 3 project with the following ionic configuration.

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.13.1 (C:\Users\AXM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:/Users/AXM/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10  ...really 11 :)
```

The initial complaints I did not log I believe where about sass failing.
Googling I run into this post though not specifically about "ionic 3" saying downgrade.

[Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612707/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-with-uns)

```
  "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch && beep ",
        "serve:before": "watch",
        "emulate:before": "build",
        "deploy:before": "build",
        "build:before": "build",
        "run:before": "build",
        "run:after": "beep",
        "serve:after": "beep",
        "beep": "bash.exe beep.sh",
        "beep0": "bash.exe -c \"echo -en '\\a' \" ",
        "releasePWA": "ionic cordova build browser --prod --release"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/android-full-screen": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/toast": "4.6.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@types/youtube": "0.0.46",
        "archiver": "^5.3.1",
        "child_process": "^1.0.2",
        "clipboard-js": "0.3.3",
        "com.verso.cordova.clipboard": "https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git",
        "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
        "cordova-clipboard": "~1.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.7.1-dev",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "~5.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "~2.6.0",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.0.3",
        "danielsogl-cordova-plugin-clipboard": "1.0.2",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "node-apk": "^1.1.1",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "url-exist": "^3.0.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
        "@types/node": "^9.6.61",
        "cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
        "cordova-plugin-apkupdater": "^4.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
        "tslint": "^5.10.0",
        "tslint-ionic-rules": "0.0.16",
        "typescript": "^2.8.3",
        "viewport-units-buggyfill": "0.6.2"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [
        {
            "platform": "android",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "android"
        },
        {
            "platform": "browser",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "browser"
        }
    ],
    "description": "UPS.ion: project",
    "config": {
        "ionic_source_map": "source-map",
        "ionic_copy": "./copy.config.js"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
            "cordova-clipboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "com.verso.cordova.clipboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-apkupdater": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser"
        ]
    }
}
```

Anyway I am poor at resolving issues like these here is my package.json I am not back to Node v10.16.0, not fully recovered with some weird new issues when I build

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod --release
```

I get

```
> ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform browser
[07:44:15] ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4
[07:44:15] build prod started ...
[07:44:15] clean started ...
[07:44:15] clean finished in 2 ms
[07:44:15] copy started ...
[07:44:15] deeplinks started ...
[07:44:15] deeplinks finished in 293 ms
[07:44:15] ngc started ...
[07:44:20] typescript error
Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule in S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/src/app/app.module.ts' -
only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [[object Object], Clipboard in
S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/node_modules/@ionic-native/clipboard/index.d.ts, Toast in
S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/node_modules/@ionic-native/toast/index.d.ts, SocialSharing in
S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing/index.d.ts, AndroidFullScreen in
S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/node_modules/@ionic-native/android-full-screen/index.d.ts, ?null?]

[07:44:20] ionic-app-script task: "build"
[07:44:20] Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at S:\_W\ARP\UPS.ion\SRC\UPS.ion.3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
at step (S:\_W\ARP\UPS.ion\SRC\UPS.ion.3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (S:\_W\ARP\UPS.ion\SRC\UPS.ion.3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (S:\_W\ARP\UPS.ion\SRC\UPS.ion.3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform browser exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I have googled among many other things

1. Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule
2. Error: The Angular AoT build failed

and made many guess work attempts  (npm uninstall this... npm install that...).
I also cleaned all lint errors, but it did not help either.

Funny but deleting the 5 providers list shown below lines 120..124 in app.modules.ts makes the build happy but the browser build won't run and the same with the APK build.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Perhaps there is something else that needs to be upgraded to make it possible to have a newer version of node that works for both projects (I can't afford to loose my ionic3 project).

Sorry it's complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Using different versions of Node to run each app might help. The tool [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is great for this, go ahead and install it if you haven't already.

In one shell, install your newer Node version, e.g. `nvm install lts/gallium` and `nvm use lts/gallium`. Wipe out node_modules and reinstall dependencies (`rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i`) and run your server stuff there.

In another shell, install the older Node version, e.g. `nvm install lts/erbium` and `nvm use lts/erbium`. Again, wipe out node_modules and reinstall dependencies (`rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i`) and run your Ionic 3 project there.

If that doesn't help, putting a gutted version of your app on Github with instructions to replicate the bug would best enable further debugging.